# PyQt QTreeWidget not displaying content

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I used the Qt designer to design UI (file: **tree_view_widget_ui.py**) and I have a class (file: **tree_view_widget.py**) that creates the widget and shows the data, but data is not displayed. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

**tree_view_widget.py**

```
from tree_view_widget_ui import Ui_Form

class TreeViewWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data2show):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.data2show = data2show
        self.addItems(self.ui.treeWidget.invisibleRootItem())   #not sure about this line?

    def addItems(self, parent):
        column = 0
        data_group_1 = self.addParent(parent, column, 'Group1', 'data Clients')

        for data in self.data2show:
            self.addChild(data_item, column, data.prop1, data.prop2)

    def addParent(self, parent, column, title, data):
        item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [title])
        item.setData(column, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, data)
        item.setChildIndicatorPolicy(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.ShowIndicator)
        item.setExpanded (True)
        return item

    def addChild(self, parent, column, title, data):
        item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [title])
        item.setData(column, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, data)
        return item
```

And the GUI design file (created with Qt Designer):

**tree_view_widget_ui.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s
try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("TreeView"))
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(200, 400)
        Form.setFixedSize(200, 400)
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(Form)
        self.treeWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.treeWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 200, 400))
        self.treeWidget.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.treeWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.treeWidget.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.treeWidget.setAutoScrollMargin(16)
        self.treeWidget.setIndentation(1)
        self.treeWidget.setRootIsDecorated(True)
        self.treeWidget.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.treeWidget.setAnimated(False)
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeWidget"))
        self.treeWidget.header().setVisible(False)
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Tree View", "Tree View", None))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
```

Any suggestions how to change the code that the data will be displayed in the tree shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing any of your added items, is because you have set the column count of the tree-widget to zero (in the GUI module).

To fix this, go back to Qt Designer, select your tree-widget and scroll down to the bottom of the Property Editor. Then select the value for **columnCount** and click the little red arrow on the right to reset it back to the default.

And don't forget to re-generate your GUI module!